# Export my ng-repeat to csv - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: angularjs, export-to-csv

I am trying to create this function that loops after two arrays and export the data to csv, it emulates what two nested ng-repeat table (the first ng-repeat for headers and the second for data).

The code is still not very clean.

```
 $scope.download = function () {

                var headerarray =$scope.displayColumns;
                var array1 = [];
                var array2 = [];

                for (i = 0; i < $scope.filteredObjects.length; i++) {

                    for (j = 0; j < $scope.displayColumns.length; j++) {

                        if(i===0 && j===0) {
                            array1.push(headerarray);
                            array2.push(array1);
                            console.log(array2)
                            var str = array2.join("\n")
                            var array1 = []
                        }
              array1.push($scope.showColumnData($scope.filteredObjects[i], $scope.displayColumns[j]));


                        if (j === $scope.displayColumns.length - 1) {

                            array2.push(array1);
                            console.log(array2)
                            var str = array2.join("\n")
                            var array1 = []
                        }
                    }
                }
                console.log(str);

                console.log(str.length);

                var dl = new Blob([str], { type: 'text' });

                saveAs(dl, "export.csv")

            }
```

The output looks fine when I open the file in Excel:

[image]

And in Ron's Editor for CSV, it look like this:

[image]

In notepad+

[image]

But when I open it in pure notepad, it's one liner like this:

[image]

I am afraid my csv format isn't totally correct? There's something that Excel and Ron's are recognizing but by pure notepad?

Comment: it depends on application configuration. It is not your code issue.

Comment: did you try var dl = new Blob([str], { type: 'text/csv' });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want line breaks to display fine in Notepad you have to use `\r\n` instead of just `\n` since it is following Microsoft newline format.

You can see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations_in_different_character_encoding_specifications for more detail.